# Ble Broadcast receiver not displaying on listview

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

(DISCLAIMER: SUPER NEW TO ANDROID STUDIO) I'm creating an app to scan for ble devices and display them on the list but it seems like no devices are being discovered and being displayed on the listview. Any help is appreciated. I'm planning to update the Textview with the number of devices that are found. I haven't set up the scanfilters yet since I'm still trying to figure out the UUIDs for the tags that I'm using. I also changed the min sdk to 23 since it was giving me an error while setting the scanmode, callback, and matchmode.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tygatraxseconddraft;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TWESBTSCANNER";
    public static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 11;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button scanningBtn;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private final ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.device_list);
        scanningBtn = findViewById(R.id.scanning_btn);


        hasPermissions();

        checkBluetoothState();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.device_list);

        scanningBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                BluetoothLeScanner scanner = adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


                final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() { //studio made it not private
                    @Override
                    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                        // ...do whatever you want with this found device
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                        // Ignore for now
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                        // Ignore for now
                    }
                };

                UUID SERVICE_DATA_UUID = UUID.fromString("00005246-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");//filter for the Nordic tags
                UUID[] serviceUUIDs = new UUID[]{SERVICE_DATA_UUID};
                List<ScanFilter> filters = null;
                if (serviceUUIDs != null) {
                    filters = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (UUID serviceUUID : serviceUUIDs) {
                        ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                                .setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUUID))
                                .build();
                        filters.add(filter);
                    }
                }


                ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                        .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
                        .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
                        .setReportDelay(0L)
                        .build();

                if (scanner != null) {
                    scanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback); // must set scan settings first
                    Log.d(TAG, "scan started");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "could not get scanner object");

                }
            }
        });



    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { //
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));

            }
        }
    };


    private boolean hasPermissions() { //checks and asks for location permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //ENABLE WHEN TESTING ON PHONE
    private void checkBluetoothState() {
        //gets the bluetooth adapter
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        }//requests permission if bluetooth is not enabled
    }


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tygatraxseconddraft">

    <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
             You must add an attribute to this permission, or declare the
             ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, depending on the results when you
             check location usage in your app. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>


    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
         devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
         devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_LOCATION"/>

    <!--Makes the app show up for only ble enabled devices-->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true"/>





    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TygaTraxsecondDraft">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_devices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/number_of_devices"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanning_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/device_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scanning_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/number_devices" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In case this is needed
**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="gray">#7393B3</color>
</resources>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Tyga Trax (second draft)</string>
    <string name="button_text">Scan</string>
    <string name="number_of_devices">There are </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I see you already thought requesting the permissions, but do you actually have BLE devices near you? Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to check first. Please add the manifest.xml as well, it is missing

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Hi, I just added the android manifest and fixed the headings. I have used nRF connect and found my nordic tags (called RF-B-AR4 BLE Beacon) [here](https://imgur.com/a/h5UQwe8). I have a recording and a screenshot of logcat [here](https://imgur.com/a/aRs8iKJ) .

Comment: What is the target sdk for your app? The permission requirements change for later versions

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I looked into the `build.gradle` file and it says 23:
`android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tygatraxseconddraft"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }`

Answer (score 0):

### New Answer

I just realised you are simply doing nothing with the found devices right now, your `ScanCallback` is empty. You should add something like this to see the results:

```java
final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() { //studio made it not private
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        Log.d(TAG, "BLE scan found Device " + device.getName() + " with MAC " + device.getAddress());
        // TODO: add device to ListView
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        // Ignore for now
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        // Ignore for now
    }
};
```

You should see the found devices in your log now

### Previous Answer

You are requesting the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission but your target SDK is 31. The guide for [Bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions) states

> **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** is necessary because a Bluetooth scan can gather information about the location of the user. This information may come from the user's own devices, as well as Bluetooth beacons in use at locations such as shops and transit facilities.

and also

> Note: If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, you can declare the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission instead of the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

It even states to use `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` for devices with Android 10 or above. But there are new permissions for a target SDK of 31 (Android 12) as stated in [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions) document.

```xml
<manifest>
    <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
         You must add an attribute to this permission, or declare the
         ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, depending on the results when you
         check location usage in your app. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
         devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
         devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

As you can see the legacy Bluetooth permissions like `BLUETOOTH` are added as well, but have the option `android:maxSdkVersion="30"` set to only work up to Android 11.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I'll update my post with the current code. Do you have any other ideas as to why it's not working?

Comment: Could you add your log output to your question?

Comment: I copied it to a .txt file and uploaded it to my drive. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19UYiG4WHrHuKdFeoDR4vqccr4M1IUvJ8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Stealthninja146 please take a look at my updated answer

Comment: I tried it out but it still didn't work. I'm thinking there's something just very wrong in my code and I'm gonna try something else. Thanks for the help.